# How to get following field in UPS Web Service Developer Kit in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ups

I have download UPS Developer Kit to be used with Visual Studio 2012.
I try to get the "Package Type" and "Return Service Type". (See example below). I have tried to read the manual but still couldn't find them. Please help.

```
Package Type 
Package types. Values are:
    01 = UPS Letter,
    02 = Customer Supplied Package, 
    03 = Tube, 
    04 = PAK, 
    21= UPS Express Box,
    24 = UPS 25KG Box,
    25 = UPS 10KG Box,
    30 = Pallet, 
    2a = Small Express Box, 
    2b = Medium Express Box,
    2c = Large Express Box

Return Service Type 
    2 = UPS Print and Mail (PNM) 
    3 = UPS Return Service 1- Attempt (RS1) 
    5 =UPS Return Service 3-Attempt (RS3) 
    8 =UPS Electronic Return Label (ERL) 
    9 = UPS Print Return Label
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Shipping Package Web Services Developers Guide, version *December 30, 2013*, PDF **Page 379**, you can see all the code field for Packaging.Code for the **Packaging Type**.

And for the **Return Service Code**, on the same document, look at **Page 40**, ReturnService/Code.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing similar kind of implementation and I do not think they support to fetch them real time through their service. So I guess this has to be in local database. I am happy to find out the solution you implemented if it is different to having them in a local DB.